# Split complex string within a muliple sub string with same special character

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to parse the string with semicolon with multiple substrings, here are the example

```
String temp = "SIM1_TM_4G3G2G_DE;ANY_RAT;TCNAME_Flight_Mode_Toggle;TIME_60;120;90;30"
```

Expected output required would be to display only values after the `TIME_`:

```
60
120
90
30
```

I have tried with the following code it did not do the following need

```
String[] args_val=temp.split(";");


log("STARTING THE LOOP");
for(int ix=0; ix<args_val.length;ix++)
{
    log("args_val["+ix+"]-" +args_val[ix]);
    //TIME is considered in seconds
    if(args_val[ix].contains(TIME"))
    {   
        log("args_val[ix] length -" +args_val[ix].length());
        String sTime = args_val[ix].substring(args_val[ix].indexOf("TIME_") +5, args_val[ix].length());
        log("print sTime-" +sTime);                 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String output = temp.substring(temp.indexOf("TIME_") + 5)
                    .replaceAll(";", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may remove all the substring from start till and including `;TIME_` with the [`.*;TIME_`](https://regex101.com/r/YrotMc/1) regex (note that the `.*` is a greedy dot matching pattern and will match from the start of the string till the last `;TIME_` on the line), and then split the rest with `;`:

```
String temp = "SIM1_TM_4G3G2G_DE;ANY_RAT;TCNAME_Flight_Mode_Toggle;TIME_60;120;90;30";
String[] res = temp.replaceFirst(".*;TIME_", "").split(";");
System.out.println(res[0]);
System.out.println(res[1]);
System.out.println(res[2]);
System.out.println(res[3]);
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/Gy0ejD)

This will work if the string you mention is always in this format.